# How to use SPLIT to save different files in R

Tags: r, split, save

I have a data frame which I would like to save as different .csv files based on the values of a variable.

Following some example lines and columns from the data frame:

```
PPT     INDEX
ppt01   12
ppt01   13
ppt01   16
ppt01   16
ppt01   17
ppt01   18
ppt01   18
ppt01   19
ppt01   19
ppt01   23
ppt01   24
ppt01   24
ppt01   26
ppt01   27
ppt02   12
ppt02   13
ppt02   16
ppt02   16
ppt02   17
ppt02   27
ppt02   28
ppt02   29
ppt02   30
ppt02   30
ppt02   31
ppt03   12
ppt03   13
ppt03   16
ppt03   16
ppt03   17
ppt03   31
ppt03   32
ppt03   32
ppt03   33
```

I would like to save the data frame into different files based on *PPT* column. For example: "newfile_ppt01.csv"

```
PPT     INDEX
ppt01   12
ppt01   13
ppt01   16
ppt01   16
ppt01   17
ppt01   18
ppt01   18
ppt01   19
ppt01   19
ppt01   23
ppt01   24
ppt01   24
ppt01   26
ppt01   27
```

"newfile_ppt02.csv"

```
PPT     INDEX
ppt02   12
ppt02   13
ppt02   16
ppt02   16
ppt02   17
ppt02   27
ppt02   28
ppt02   29
ppt02   30
ppt02   30
ppt02   31
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all unique ppt's and save each one of them:

```
for (ppt in unique(data$PPT)) {
  write.csv(data["PPT" == ppt,], file = paste0("newfile_", ppt, ".csv"))
}
```

Comment: for some reason it saves the different files according to the PPT number, but the file has only the row names, no other rows/values appear. I think it's because of this part of the code `data["PPT" == ppt,]`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `for (ppt in unique(data$PPT)) {
  write.csv(data[data$PPT == ppt,], file = paste0("newfile_", ppt, ".csv"))
}` works.

Comment: Yes, my bad. My `data` was data.table rather than data.frame like yours

Answer (score 0):

In R, you should always avoid `for` loop. Using functions from the `apply` family is always recommended.

Assuming your data is of this format:

```
df <- data.frame(
  PPT=c("ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt02", "ppt02", "ppt03", "ppt03", "ppt03"),
  INDEX=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
)
```

Converting `factor` to `character`:

`df$PPT <- as.character(df$PPT)`

Now you split your data according to values on `PPT` column:

```
df_list <- split(df, df$PPT)
```

Using `lapply`, you can save each splitted data:

```
lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i){
  write.csv(df_list[[i]], paste0(df_list[[i]][1,1], ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: this code results in one single file (called 'NA.csv') with only the row names.

Comment: Well, it is working here. There should be something wrong with your data, since you didn't gave us a reproducible example I needed to simulate a df. I update the answer with the data I simulated.

Comment: `you should always avoid for loop. Using functions from the apply family is always recommended.` this is not strictly true. Given the fact `apply` is a `for loop` (albeit a little more efficient), it has no effect whatsoever in this case. Most of the advantage of `apply` is lost in this example.